# Bold vs Code Formatting in Suggested Edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, code-formatting

Every once in a while I see suggested edits that mostly consist of bolding things. For example, [this specific example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4305502) took a bunch of "TableNames" and made them into "**TableNames**".

It seems to me that `TableNames` would be a more appropriate choice of formatting. I had decided to reject this edit, but it had already gotten approved.

Is there a preferred stylistic choice in this area? Was I wrong in wanting to reject this suggested edit?

Comment: Also, instead of rolling back, I made an edit on top of it... that may have also been the wrong way to handle it. Feedback?

Comment: Generally bolding is reserved for headings . nobody bolds code

Comment: @JeffBridgman that edit was fine, if you hadn't done it I would have rolled back...

Comment: I would have used code formatting, as well. Though, I would have made other changes such as put the example record on it's own line. I think making the "correct" edit instead of rolling back makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `this style` when it's a language keyword, for example `int`, `struct my_struct;`.

When it comes to tables, it's a matter of taste, since it's case-insensitive and it's not really a code. I don't think it's a problem changing "table" to **"table"**, it looks better and easier to understand when looking without actually reading each word that it's a name of a table. Without making it bold, it would be harder to seek it in this context.